# Please stop adding chat notifications when I'm actually just using mobile

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, mobile-web

Regardless of the actual functionality of [mobile chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22mobile+chat%22&room=35), one thing that really bugs me is that if I do chat on mobile, somehow the supernoticollider thinks that I need to have every single message I have received while using mobile chat as a notification, as if I'd been away.

[image: The Bridge]

Please stop doing this.

---

Okay so apparently I should click the 'mention' button. This is terrible.

Comment: Please stop using mobile chat.

Comment: Oh look, I'm famous!

Comment: You didn't click the button (this behaviour is very much bydesign, per balpha).

Comment: @TimStone Yes, I understand now that there's a button to prevent this, but it's a terrible, terrible button in a terrible, terrible place, with terrible, terrible text. (I assumed clicking the button called 'mention' would mention that person in a message, rather than dismiss a future notification. Note: clicking this button hides my keyboard, which is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "mention" button on mobile chat:

[image: mention button screenshot]

Tap to dismiss the notification - just like how you'd dismiss a full-chat ping notification (with the circle button on your avatar).

Comment: This is not really very discoverable. It's nice to know, but it would have been nicer to know without having to come to meta to figure it out.

Comment: @Feichinger Replying to a chat message also hides the chat ping. This doesn't happen in mobile chat.

Comment: @StrixVaria Don't ever expect mobile chat to tell you anything. In fact, don't ever expect mobile chat to anything.